# Office Add-in marketplace testing - Force fallback from SSO

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We're working on a Microsoft Outlook add-in that we're looking to put into the Office marketplace. We've been failed on our review with

"1120.3.6.39 SSO Functionality"

> Please implement a fallback method for single sign on (SSO) for cases when users of the add-in are on hosts that don’t support SSO or SSO doesn’t succeed for other reasons.
> Additional information on fallback methods can be found in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins?view=word-js-preview#requirements-and-best-practices

We've not been able to recreate this in our environment. We believe in test that failed was on  Desktop Outlook on Windows 10. Is there a way of recreating this so SSO will not succeed so it will trigger our fallback code?

Comment: I interpret that message as saying that you don't have fallback code (not that they actually experienced an error with SSO). Are you saying that you do?

Comment: To simulate an error, you can just use a [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) statement. Without seeing your code, it's hard to know where it should go. Try putting it just above the line that calls `getAccessToken`.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks that's a good shout we have been able to break our add-in by having just throwing an error and falling back to try our next authenticator rather than respecting the documented error codes. We've done this with our first fallback calling `Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync` which doesn't appear to have any documented error codes. When that fails we can get into our "fallback" authenticator.

Comment: In that case, it seems that you do have fallback support, so I'm puzzled at the failure from AppSource. I think their reports give you some way to contact them if you have a question.

Comment: **UPDATE** Once we got in contact with the App Source review team we figured out that the test case related to 1120.3.6.36 wasn't working as expected. In the end the add-on passed the review without needing any changes.